# Python dataframe sort values select n first results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns `df['Intent', 'Question']`.

First,I do `df = df.sort_values(by=['Intent'])` in order to sort them by Intent name, and then I want for each intent ( I have 6 in total) to only get the first 100 sentences. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Intent']).groupby('Intent').head(100)
```

Comment: I only get the first 100 results from the first intent like this, whereas I want the first 100 results from every intent

Comment: @joasa works fine for my test data. Can you check again